# Play audio from tableview and advance to next file in list

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I present the user with a table view of all the audio files listed in their documents directory of the app, alphabetically.  I would like to allow advancing to the next track using headphones or the iPod audio controls built into iOS, but am not sure how to advance to whatever the next track is in the documents.  My code to play it is to simply get the path to documents, and append it with the name of the row they click on in the table view.  Is there a simple way to get the next file name from the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably get the contents of the folder in an array and then display it in a table after sorting. By this, every row points to a file in the array, which can be retrieved and played. To get the contents of a folder use the following line:

```
- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error;
```

Comment: So in the viewdidload I have
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 self.title = @"Saved Sermons";
    self.files = [[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryPath error:nil] pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mp3", nil]] retain]; 

Since I get the contents already passed into an array, and display there, how would I do this?

Comment: so self.files is the array of files I was talking about. You should loop the array to get file by file and play.